# How to optimize the count query for each categories for the search results?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have nine categories for my classfieds website. When a user search for a keyword, I want to show the search results and the number of search results in each of the categories.

How to optimize the sql query?

What have I tried? run a loop for each category:

```
select * from ads where title like '%keyword%';
select count(*) from ads where title like '%keyword%' and category_id = 1;
select count(*) from ads where title like '%keyword%' and category_id = 2;
select count(*) from ads where title like '%keyword%' and category_id = 3;
select count(*) from ads where title like '%keyword%' and category_id = 4;
.....
```

Any better suggetions to make the sql queries faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
   ,category_id 
FROM 
   ads 
WHERE 
   title like '%keyword%' 
GROUP BY category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

nickles80's query will work. but if you want to do both in one query, try this:

```
SELECT ads.*, cnt.CountResult
FROM ads
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT category_id, COUNT(1) AS CountResult
    FROM ads 
    where title like '%keyword%' 
    GROUP BY category_id
) cnt ON cnt.category_id = ads.category_id
where title like '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sum() the counts via IF() (if mysql), or case/when more generic

```
select 
      count(*) as TotalAds,
      sum( case when category_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory1,
      sum( case when category_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory2,
      sum( case when category_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory3,
      sum( case when category_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory4,
      sum( case when category_id = 5 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory5,
      sum( case when category_id = 6 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory6,
      sum( case when category_id = 7 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory7,
      sum( case when category_id = 8 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory8,
      sum( case when category_id = 9 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalCategory9
   from
      ads 
   where 
      title like '%keyword%';
```